User vandalized own question - roll back?
This question:
Content removed. I do not consent to "AI" scraping
Screenshot at the time I wrote this:

On other SE sites as well:

Rolling this back will return in a tug of war.
What to do?
Possibly relevant:
Who owns the content I post?

This person went through all their SO sites and did this to all the questions and answers they've made. It appears all have been rolled back.

Flag the questions with a custom flag. We get automatic notifications on excessive vandalism but this is probably something we want to keep an eye on.
As for what's happening...
Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow has been tying up with genAI companies to sell access to an API. We're still waiting on clarity on what this'll look like, but they're promising attribution to our posts and such.
nixCraft on Mastodon has been encouraging folks to stop contributing to SO and network sites, including deleting posts. Vandalising your posts is against the TOS, and frankly hurts the human/open web more than it hurts genAI companies who probably have scraped SE or sites scraping SE already - and practically vandalism and deleting your account the regular way does not render your content inaccessible to SE should they wish to anyway.
It also means, well it's the community who needs to deal with the fallout of someone who isn't active on the network messing with things, just like the glory days of twitter, with little actual effect on the people they want to hurt.
If there's a need, we may suspend users to keep them from vandalising their posts, and we will definitely moderator-message users as needed.

This might be a question for main meta - we don't really have the full details on implementation of these things yet.

@Gantendo: LLMs as implemented today may not be capable of attribution, but that is not a fundamental limitation of LLMs (It is very deeply embedded in the structure presently being used, there definitely is no quick fix.  But we don't know how much work has been put into competing structures, or how close to maturity they could be.)

And for your "StackExchange has no respect for its license obligations" this was a far better example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

From Chat (thanks https://superuser.com/users/1210833/notthedr01ds) there are other profiles editing and deleting their answers.
It may be worthwhile having some sort of flag for times an answer is edited significantly and "AI" is in the edit.
Evidence

Profile https://superuser.com/users/905389/ai-test-account Deleted answer: https://superuser.com/a/1589527/74026

